# Changing EditText based on user choice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a form in my app which requires the user to enter his/her height and weight. There are two radio buttons of imperial and metric units. I want to show one height edittext (meters) when the user chooses imperial in the radiogroup and two edittexts (feet + inches) for metric. How can I implement this?

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with the following code working fine.

```
     //activity.xml
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingHorizontal="15dp">


<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/imperial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Imperial" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/metric"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Metric" />
</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:hint="Input height" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feet_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Input Feet" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inches_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Input Inches" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>


//activity code
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var heightEdt: EditText
private lateinit var feetEdt: EditText
private lateinit var inchesEdt: EditText
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    heightEdt = findViewById(R.id.height_et)
    feetEdt = findViewById(R.id.feet_et)
    inchesEdt = findViewById(R.id.inches_et)
    val rg = findViewById<View>(R.id.radioGroup1) as RadioGroup
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        when (checkedId) {
            R.id.imperial -> {
                heightEdt.isVisible = true
                feetEdt.isVisible = false
                inchesEdt.isVisible = false
            }
            R.id.metric -> {
                heightEdt.isVisible = false
                feetEdt.isVisible = true
                inchesEdt.isVisible = true
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use both edittexts (in meters) and (in feet-inches) with one have android:visibility="gone"

when user selects the metric hide the another one edittext and show edittexts (feet + inches) and when user selects the imperial then hide the other and show height edittext (meters)...